# dhcp for multiple aps in home network

Tags: dhcp, wireless-networking

I'm trying to add a second wifi access point with the same SSID to a home network, and am having difficulty configuring the routers.  Many online sites explain how to set up a second wifi router that is wired to the first one.  In my situation, I need to connect both wifi routers to the home's ethernet LAN, which has a TPLink non-wifi router just upstream of the switch.  From what I understand, for this to work, the wifi routers (Netgear AC1000s--although I haven't bought the second one yet while I am experimenting) need different static IPs, different wifi channels, and DHCP disabled on both, so that the central TPLink is the only one assigning IPs.  But when I disable DCHP on the wifi router to test out this theory, nothing works.  What am I missing?  Do I have the right equipment?

Also, I have been unable to access the wifi router from my Mac via the ethernet LAN, using either the default IP or the IP assigned by the TPLink.  What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Just quick, make sure both wifi routers (not the tplink) are set in access point mode, not router mode.  Router mode requires an ip (to do routing), access point mode makes them more like a wireless bridge, and they will get their ips from upstream (if you set them up that way, you can set them up with static ips).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get no IP from the TPLink is because the Netgear Routers are setup as routers. You need to setup the Netgear routers as Access Points only.

Router functionality is to connect 2 different networks. DHCP requests don't pass from one network to the other.

Answer (score 0):

As you use a router as a AP you will end up double-NATing.

The wifi router assign the IP, and the WAN for him is the second non-wifi router.

I suggest a true AP, or maybe your router allow to switch to AP mode. That way the AP just serve the purpose to add WiFi to your first router.

Comment: The last part if your answer us incorrect. Provided the SSID, password, frequency band but different frequencies (ie 2.4 or 5 gig band ) - preferably non-overlapping channels - and encryption are the same you can seemlessly roam between any 2 access points. Expensive gear may give you more control of logins and a tighter handover process but are not neccessary for seemless coverage.

Comment: FYI, I seemlessly roam between an Asus router and Ubiquity AP more-or-less daily. No complex configuration or controller required.

Comment: @davidgo I will test, last time I tried with linksys AP it was cutting, some milliseconds, but it has a cut. but we can agree that any surfing or light use you will not see the cut

Comment: Methinks we agree more then we differ. Internet is packet (rather then circuit) switched, and yes, a few packets may be lost during the handoff **but the [TCP/IP] connection will not break**. This means video streaming will continue fine, but there may be a short disruption on a voip call (but you will not get disconnected) when switching between APs. Similarly if playing a game there might be a spike in latency but the game will continue. The IP address does not change nor should connections time out or reset. TCP streams will be OK, udp packets will drop, but the protocol allows this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable DHCP and use the LAN ports in the routers to connect to your TP-Link.